Alacritty: How to deal with multiple configurations?
I'm surprised I didn't find the answer to this question already, as I feel it must certainly be a very common problem.
I want to use different sets of settings for the different machines I use (and have common settings as well).
Importantly, I want to manage the configuration files in my dotfiles repo, so they really have to exist alongside each other.
What would be the proper way to deal with all configuration files ?

I was looking for some way to use a common configuration file but differentiate key bindings for different OSes. Claude is good at making up a fictional answer, suggesting there a condition you can apply. But, one way you can get close to what you are looking for is using import files. So your master ~/.alacritty.toml could import a number of files which end up being links into (another directory) in your dotfiles repo, such as .alacritty_lib/. The import statement will silently ignore files that don't exist. So, your base .alacritty.toml could look like this:
import = [
   "~/.alacritty_host_x.toml",
   "~/.alacritty_host_y.toml",
   "~/.alacritty_host_z.toml",
]

Then, outside of your dotfiles repo, on host x, create the link ~/.alacritty_host_x.toml which references .alacritty_lib/host_x.toml. On host y, create a y link and likewise on host z.
If we could go back in time and were working on Apollo Domain OS, we could have links reference environment variables and things could be glorious.
